# Java 1.7/1.8 JIT Compiler broken?

Tags: java, jvm, fatal-error, jit

I have a problem with some code from GlazedList 1.8 that causes a SIGSEGV when running under java 1.8_05/64 bit/FC20 & Windows 8.

I have the disassembled output (`-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions '-XX:CompileCommand=print,*BoyerMooreCaseInsensitiveTextSearchStrategy.indexOf'` see below) but I no clue on how to debug it.

So any help with debugging the code or a hint to where to ask for help is appreciated.

The disassembled code is more than 30000 chars. long so you will have to go here https://java.net/jira/browse/GLAZEDLISTS-564?focusedCommentId=378982&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-378982 to read the code

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdc2d93bcfc, pid=12092, tid=140582414018304
```

> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build
> 1.8.0_05-b13)  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> Problematic frame:
>
> J 12756 C2
>
> ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.filter.BoyerMooreCaseInsensitiveTextSearchStrategy.indexOf(Ljava/lang/String;)I
> (147 bytes) @ 0x00007fdc2d93bcfc [0x00007fdc2d93baa0+0x25c]

Comment: Have you tried disabling the JIT compiler for the specific classes mentioned in a previous comment on that issue? That issue also appears to be reported for jre 1.7_21, so your question about the 1.8 JIT compiler being broken seems misleading. It appears this has been a longstanding issue.  https://java.net/jira/browse/GLAZEDLISTS-564?focusedCommentId=375729&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-375729

Comment: Yes, disabling JIT compilation eliminates the problem. And the problem is also present in 1.7.x

Comment: Have you searched the bug database/reported it to Oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed a JIT compiler bug. I've verified that it exists in JDK 7u67, 8u11 as well as in the latest JDK 9 sources. Here is the reduced test case:

```
public class CharArrayCrash {
    static char[] pattern0 = {0};
    static char[] pattern1 = {1};

    static void test(char[] array) {
        if (pattern1 == null) return;

        int i = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        char c = array[pos];

        while (i >= 0 && (c == pattern0[i] || c == pattern1[i])) {
            i--;
            pos--;
            if (pos != -1) {
                c = array[pos];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            test(new char[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

The crash happens on array access instruction where the array offset is illegal (0xffffffff).
Seems like JIT incorrectly reorders decrement and array load instructions.

Anyway, I've submitted the bug report to Oracle: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054478